# Can't Change Value of Kendo Dropdown with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui

I'm creating a drop down select in html and trying to change the value displayed in it with jQuery.

```
  <form id="my-form">
    <select id="my-select">
      <option>Option 1</option>
      <option>Option 2</option>
      <option>Option 3</option>
    </select>
  </form>
```

With my Javascript file as

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $("#my-select").kendoDropDownList().data("kendoDropDownList");
   $("#my-select").val("Option 2");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

For some reason, when using the `kendoDropdownList`, trying to set the value of the select does not work when using plain old `jquery's` `.val()` function. Instead, use the `kendo-ui` API `.value()` like so:

```
$(document).ready( function() {
    // create a dropdown with Kendo. notice I set the value returned to a variable
    var my_dropdown = $("#my-select").kendoDropDownList().data("kendoDropDownList");

    // set the kendo dropdown to display a value using kendo api. this works
    my_dropdown.value("Option 2");

    // notice how this does nothing. the value remains 'option 2'
    $("#my-select").val("Option 3");
});
```

Here is a working example: [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/namrzu0q/32/)

Comment: I thought I had an issue with the way I was using jquery, when it was really an issue with `kendo-ui`. I hope someone finds this useful since I thought I would be able to do it with jquery and I was just doing something wrong in regards to that.

Comment: Sadly, none of those options are working for me.